# Is the question asking how to pronounce "dad" in Arabic on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, off-topic

I'm referring to [How can I pronounce the Arabic Dad?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/5965/2795).  It basically asks how "Dad" is pronounced in Arabic.

Personally, I'd consider it off-topic for the reason:

> **Question about the grammatical rules or specific characteristics of a language**.
>
> Use this reason when a question asks for an explanation of grammatical rules or specific characteristics of a language rather than asking about techniques or resources for learning or teaching a language. Consider leaving a comment directing the user to a language-specific site if there is one for the language they're asking about. If the question is good quality and should be migrated, consider flagging for moderator attention.

It's not really about techniques or resources for learning languages---it's one of these micro (not macro) questions.  But [murshad's comment](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/5965/how-can-i-pronounce-the-arabic-dad#comment8516_5965) makes me hesitate:

> I have seen phoneme production discussed here before, so I do not feel this to be much out of place.

Maybe I'm missing something.

**Question**: Is the question asking how to pronounce "dad" in Arabic on topic?

Comment: I must ask how my question could become more suitable for the site, for I do not know how. I have edited it to be specifically about [ɮˤ] for the moment, removing any mention of Arabic.

Comment: The site is [about](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/tour) *techniques of second-language acquisition and language teaching*, so the question could be edited to become on-topic by generalizing it to something like: *What tools can I use to practice Arabic pronunciation?* or *Is there a database containing common words pronounced in Arabic?*

Answer (score 2):

The question asks for specific instructions for a specific sound in a specific language, not

- "How can I learn this?" (It's really, "How do I do this?");
- methods for improving pronunciation in a specific language in general;
- hard-to-found resources about improving pronunciation in a specific language.

For these reasons, I consider the question off topic.